# Unnecessary select Primary Key sequence calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I recently switched to from using integer sequence IDs to UUIDs for primary keys in my Rails 3 app using Postgresql, using a method similar to [this method](http://ariejan.net/2008/08/12/ruby-on-rails-uuid-as-your-activerecord-primary-key/). As such, none of my tables have sequences, yet Rails is still making (what I believe to be) unnecessary calls to select sequences when records are created. For example:

```
 PK and serial sequence (1.3ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"posts"'::regclass
```

I believe this is generated by the function pk_and_sequence_for, the relevant part of my schema is:

```
t.uuid   "id", :null => false, :primary => true
```

The uuid type is just a 32 char.

Could anyone enlighten me with an elegant way to prevent Rails from making this query? (Or explain why it is necessary).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That query is examining the database catalogue to see if the primary key of the "posts" table is attached to a sequence or not, rather than trying to get a value from a sequence.